# Webpack config output filename using square brackets params instead of a plain text

Tags: webpack, build, filenames, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

In `webpack.config.js`, in `output.filename` I see square brackets. What does that mean? What's the difference between using that and a plain text?

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',

    // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    publicPath: 'dist/'
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are placeholders that Webpack will replace with their actual value.

You can read more about it in the official docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename.

These are the available options:

> - `[hash]`: The hash of the module identifier.
> - `[chunkhash]`: The hash of the chunk content.
> - `[name]`: The module name.
> - `[id]`: The module identifier.
> - `[query]`: The module query, i.e., the string following ? in the filename.

For example, if you Webpack config looks like this:

```
{
    entry : {
        a: '...',
        b: '...',
        c: '...'
    },


    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    }
}
```

Webpack will generate 3 output files, one for each key inside `entry`: `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js`.

The difference between `[hash]` and `[chunkhash]` is that the former is generated per build, while the later is generated per output file.

That has a number of advantages, as if you are using hashes as cache-busters, maybe you generate a new build where only one of your files changes, but you will still force your users to re-download all of them. If you use `[chunkhash]`, only the file that has changed will be downloaded again.

Also, remember not to use `[chunkhash]` in development mode, as that will make your build slower.

Comment: thanks for replying quickly. in the context of output how is the name decided at run-time?

Comment: @kumar The `[name]` placeholder will be replaced by each `key` inside `entry` in compilation time. In this case, the 3 values that `[name]` will be replaced with each time you trigger a build are `a`, `b` and `c`.